# Loop exits after 100 count while creating domains using python

Tags: python, arcpy, domains

I am trying to create domains on feature class or table class by reading a table which holds all look up information. Following is example code for what I am doing:

```
tableIndex = tableClasses.index("LookupTable")  
tableGnLookup = tableClasses[tableIndex]  

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tableGnLookup,   
                           ["DATA_TABLE", "DATA_REF", "LOOKUP_TABLE", "LOOKUP_REF", "LOOKUP_DESCRIPTION"],   
                           where_clause="DATA_TABLE IS NOT NULL AND LOOKUP_TABLE IS NOT NULL",   
                           sql_clause=["", "ORDER BY LOOKUP_TABLE, DATA_TABLE"])  as cursor:  

    # Itrate each row  
    for row in cursor:  

        # Get row values  
        dataTableName = str(row[0])  
        dataRefField = str(row[1])  
        lookupTableName = str(row[2])  
        lookupRefField = str(row[3])  
        lookupDescriptionField = str(row[4])  

        # Find table in all tables  
        try:  
            tableIndex = tableClasses.index(lookupTableName)  
        except:  
            tableIndex = -1  

        # Get table if table index is found  
        if tableIndex >= 0:  
            lookupTable = tableClasses[tableIndex]  
            arcpy.TableToDomain_management(lookupTable, lookupRefField, lookupDescriptionField, database, lookupTableName, lookupTableName)  

        # Find feature class in feature class list  
        try:  
            tableIndex = featureClasses.index(dataTableName)  
        except:  
            tableIndex = -1  

        # Get feature class at found index  
        if tableIndex >= 0:  
            fc = featureClasses[tableIndex]  
            try:  
                arcpy.RemoveDomainFromField_management(fc, dataRefField)  
            except Exception as e:  
                print e.message  

            try:  
                # Assign domain to field  
                arcpy.AssignDomainToField_management(fc, dataRefField, domainName)  

            except Exception as e:  
                print e.message
```

This function works fine for 100 loops but exits after that without any error or warnings. I tried to iterate loop by just printing output which give me ~500 rows. Could anyone please help me to identify the problem here?

**Edit: Just tried creating more than 100 domains and assigning them to field which worked well so there must be something wrong in this code**

Comment: Probably not the problem, but why is the sql prefix in your sql_clause an empty string instead of `None`?  Just so used to seeing a None there...

Comment: Have you tried printing exceptions where you're setting `tableIndex = -1` ?

Comment: 100 sounds like a round number so have you tried to just write a code snippet that just runs `AssignDomainToField` 101 times to see if that stops at 100?

Comment: Have you tried removing your try/except statements and running your code from IDLE?  Doing that should make seeing any error thrown easy.

Comment: You seem to have created two accounts.  Would you be able to follow [these instructions to merge them](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP, please?